# Regular Expression Error in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to search through a database of sofware titles for those that have an interior capital letter (e.g PowerPoiint, inCase).

I tried

```
select * from table where field REGEXP '^([a-z][A-Z]+)+$'
```

This seemed to work as it returned a subset of the table and *most* were correct but a fair amount were not (e.g Alias).  Clearly it is doing something right but not sure what; could it be that the ascii is somehow messed up?

Comment: As documented under [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html): "*`REGEXP` is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.*"

Comment: I think it should be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY field REGEXP '[a-z][A-Z]+[a-z]';` actually.

Comment: I think you could safely remove the last "+"-quantifier and the parentheses. So the regexp becomes ^[a-z][A-Z]+$ -- I'm not sure if having the + quantifier outside the parenthese is what generates the error, but nonetheless it's clearner and the same result ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone, new to mysql didn't know that. the Binary worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your RegEx pattern:

```
^[A-z]+[A-Z][A-z]+$
```

It will match all the examples above (PowerPoint, inCase), and not match 'Alias', one of the examples that you are having trouble with.